# How to write to page in javascript using date method

Tags: javascript

I want to display a quote depending on what day it is. Example: Quote of the day is Tuesday March 10 : "Quote here". I have the alert displaying the date, day and time but I want it to display on the page in the h2 header. So after it loads the alert I want the quote, depending on which day it is, to be written on the page.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Class 6 array assignment starter file</title>

<script>

var venomArray = new Array();
venomArray[0] = "  Ability is nothing without opportunity - Napoleon Bonaparte";
venomArray[1] = " Nothing happens unless first we dream - Carl Sandburg";
venomArray[2] = "quote3";

var today = new Date();
//var text = document.getElementById('expression').firstChild.nodeValue  = venomArray[i];

// if I uncomment this, It displays the index 1 for tuesday. How do I get it to write to the page? Would I use firstChildnodeValue?
alert("The quote of the day for: "+today+ venomArray[today.getDay()-1]);


</script>
</head>

<body>
 <section>
 <h2 style = "color:red" id='expression'>  Quote of the Day : </h2> 



<h3> All of the Quotes are listed below:</h3>
 <p>

 Nothing happens unless first we dream - Carl Sandburg<br>
 Believe you can and you're halfway there - Theodore Roosevelt<br>
 A place for everything, everything in its place - Benjamin Franklin<br>
 Don't let the fear of striking out hold you back - Babe Ruth<br>
 We can't help everyone, but everyone can help someone - Ronald Reagan<br>
 With self-discipline most anything is possible - Theodore Roosevelt
 </p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.. This may help your question

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Class 6 array assignment starter file</title>


</head>

<body>
 <section>
 <h2 style = "color:red" id='expression'>  Quote of the Day : <span id="quote"></span> </h2> 



<h3> All of the Quotes are listed below:</h3>
 <p>

 Nothing happens unless first we dream - Carl Sandburg<br>
 Believe you can and you're halfway there - Theodore Roosevelt<br>
 A place for everything, everything in its place - Benjamin Franklin<br>
 Don't let the fear of striking out hold you back - Babe Ruth<br>
 We can't help everyone, but everyone can help someone - Ronald Reagan<br>
 With self-discipline most anything is possible - Theodore Roosevelt
 </p>
</section>
 <script type="text/javascript">

var venomArray = new Array();
venomArray[0] = "  Ability is nothing without opportunity - Napoleon Bonaparte";
venomArray[1] = " Nothing happens unless first we dream - Carl Sandburg";
venomArray[2] = "quote2";
  venomArray[3] = "quote3";
    venomArray[4] = "quote4";

var t = new Date();
//alert(t.getDay());
//var text = document.getElementById('expression').firstChild.nodeValue  = venomArray[i];

// if I uncomment this, It displays the index 1 for tuesday. How do I get it to write to the page? Would I use firstChildnodeValue?
// alert("The quote of the day for: "+today+ venomArray[today.getDay()-1]);
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = venomArray[t.getDay()-1];

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the innerHTML property of the  element

> document.getElementById("expression").innerHTML = '  Quote of the Day : ' + 
>   today+venomArray[today.getDay()-1];

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHtml property of an element to update the content, something like:

```
document.getElementById('expression').innerHTML = "Quote";
```

This is an implementation in pure JavaScript. You usually use some kind of templating now a days to display variable text in a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Use This :-

```
<script>

var venomArray = new Array();
venomArray[0] = "  Ability is nothing without opportunity - Napoleon Bonaparte";
venomArray[1] = " Nothing happens unless first we dream - Carl Sandburg";
venomArray[2] = "quote3";

var today = new Date();
//var text = document.getElementById('expression').firstChild.nodeValue  = venomArray[i];

// if I uncomment this, It displays the index 1 for tuesday. How do I get it to write to the page? Would I use firstChildnodeValue?
//alert("The quote of the day for: "+today+ venomArray[today.getDay()-1]);



/*Add this Code*/



 var display_date = "today"+ venomArray[today.getDay()-1];
    $('h2').html(display_date );

</script>
```